# how to tell cpanm Image::Magick about header location?

Tags: macos, perl, installation, imagemagick, cpan

On OS X cpanm Image::Magick fails with

> Magick.xs:60:10: fatal error: 'magick/MagickCore.h' file not found
>
> #include < magick/MagickCore.h>

The file is present though. (That space is from me to have it display here.)

How can I tell cpanm and/or Image::Magick where to find those headers?

(IM is installed from source.)

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: download Module, edit Makefile.PL (add header dir to includes), make, make install as written on the imagemagick homepage.

Comment: I got a similar error during Image::Magick install using CPAN shell. Do I have to redownload the source files and then make the edits? If not can you tell me where the Makefile.PL is present to make these changes.

Comment: I don't know whether you have to redownload, the files you obtained might be on your system already, I don't know where though. If you download from the CPAN website with a web browser, extract the contents of the file and in the upper most folder of the extracted files where there are files, there is the Makefile.PL file.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is rather old, I still ran into this issue recently.

I was able to resolve it with new ImageMagick installed via homebrew (`brew install imagemagick` which installed version 6.9.5-3), then firing up `cpan` and installing `JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz` package.

It fails in test section. Thus I analysed what tests fails and decided to cheat a bit (I don't need all ImageMagick functions). I manually edited tests files (use `look Image::Magick` to get into unarchived package) – for me, it was required to completely comment out test for `input.miff` (*reference/filter/Segment.miff*) in `t/filter.t` and tests for MPEG read in `t/mpeg/read.t`. Then cpan is able to process *Image::Magick* finally.

I ran my own tests upon set of GIF and PNG images and these are OK. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You don't have to run the test suite to install a perl package. With manual installation you just skip the `make test` step, with cpanm or cpm you add `--no-test` etc.